# How to launch Android application using  GPRS connectivity

Tags: android, service, gprs

I read the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397286/android-launch-an-app-from-remote-server) but not able to find the suitable answer . so my question is there any way to launch an application remotely using GPRS connection or How to send notification to application to start the service when there is GPRS connection available.

Remark:Google Cloud Messaging is also not my choice.

Comment: Is there any other way except Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html), the successor to Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM).